# XSD Schema specify namespace for child elements other than target namespace typed in root node

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

can i override "declare a different namespace from target namespace in the root node " for a child element in the XML "W3.org XSD schema ?

Comment: this is not possible. you shoud create a new xsd file for that element. and then use xs:import element

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this? (look at sr2:package) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://source1.org"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:sr2="http://source2.org">

  <xs:element name="sr2:package">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="foo" type="typeFromSource1Schema" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>

Answer (score 0):

You must use different schema for a different namespace ,then add Import attribute in Element tag which reference that tpe,